How to use the 'include' tag in the client with LiquidJS
I've been using LiquidJS to render templates within the client side JS of a webpage. LiquidJS supports the ability to include a template within another template with the include tag.
The problem I am facing is that this tag when used on the server side will automatically pull the template from the templates folder and include it, but when calling it in the browser I receive the error:
RenderError: Not Found
Which I assume is because it does not know where the included template can be found. I took a look through the documentation, but don't see the ability to provide the inner template when rendering the outer template. Is this functionality simply not possible in the client, or is there some other way I can provide both templates to the render function?
Here are the two templates I am attempting to use:
summary-block.liquid
<table id="bookingSummary" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Price Group</th>
            <th>Unit Total</th>
            <th>Subtotal</th>
            <th>Discount</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
            <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for group in summary.summaryGroups %}
            {% include 'summary-group-block' %}
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="text-end">{{summary.summaryGroups | sum: "unitTotal" | default:0}}</td>
            <td class="text-end">{{summary.summaryGroups | sum: "subtotal" | default:0 | price}}</td>
            <td class="text-end">{{summary.summaryGroups | avgSkipZero: "discount" | default: 0 | percentage}}</td>
            <td class="text-end">{{summary.summaryGroups | sum: "savings" | default: 0 | price}}</td>
            <td class="text-end">{{summary.summaryGroups | sum: "total" | default: 0 | price}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

summary-group-block.liquid
<tr>
    <td>{{group.bookingGroupLabel}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{group.unitTotal}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{group.subtotal | price}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{group.discount | percentage}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{group.savings | price}}</td>
    <td class="text-end">{{group.total | price}}</td>
</tr>


So as it turns out the process should be pretty much the same on the client as an the server. You can still use the root engine option to specify the path to the view files on the server. The cavat with that being that the view files must be accessible in the client (obviously).
Adding the following to my Liquid engine initialization allowed me to skip manually grabbing the templates and allowed for using nested templates (when the .liquid templates are available at "views/partials/booking" ):
var liquidEngine = new liquidjs.Liquid({root: "/views/partials/booking/", extname: '.liquid'})

Then you can simply use the following to render the template directly without the need of pulling the template markup:
liquidEngine.renderFile("summary-block", data)

